# I have made a quiz app and i want to save my options selected for questions and use them in my review activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have made a quiz app and i want to save my options selected for questions and use them in my review activity, but I am not getting how to do that, see if anybody can help....

Here is my Quiz Activity code:

```
public class NumberSystem1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;

    private NumberSystem1QuestionBank mNumberSystem1QuestionBank = new NumberSystem1QuestionBank();

    private TextView mScoreView;
    private TextView times;//For Timer in Quiz
    private TextView mQuestionView;
    private ImageView mQuestionImageView;

    private RadioButton mButtonChoice1;
    private RadioButton mButtonChoice2;
    private RadioButton mButtonChoice3;
    private RadioButton mButtonChoice4;

    private String mAnswer;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0;

    private int count_correct_answer =0;
    private int count_wrong_answer=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testactivity1);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.clearCheck();

        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        mQuestionImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choice3);
        mButtonChoice4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choice4);

        final Button go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        updateQuestion();

        // Set the timer for Quiz
        times = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
// method which will set the things up for our game
        times.setText("00:02:00");
// A timer of 20 minutes to play for, with an interval of 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
        NumberSystem1Activity.CounterClass timer = new NumberSystem1Activity.CounterClass(30000, 1000);
        timer.start();
        //Code Ends here


        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mButtonChoice1.isChecked()) {

                    if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                        //Post Question Delay Code
                        final Handler handle = new Handler();
                        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                //Code Ends hers
                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                        };
                        handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                        mScore = mScore + 3;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        count_correct_answer++;
                        mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(NumberSystem1Activity.this, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        //Post Question Delay Code
                        final Handler handle = new Handler();
                        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                //Code Ends hers
                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                        };
                        handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                        mScore = (mScore - 1);
                        count_wrong_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(NumberSystem1Activity.this, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } else if (mButtonChoice2.isChecked()) {

                    if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                        //Post Question Delay Code
                        final Handler handle = new Handler();
                        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                //Code Ends hers
                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                        };
                        handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                        mScore = mScore + 3;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        count_correct_answer++;
                        mButtonChoice2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(NumberSystem1Activity.this, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        //Post Question Delay Code
                        final Handler handle = new Handler();
                        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                //Code Ends hers
                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                        };
                        handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                        mScore = (mScore - 1);
                        count_wrong_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        mButtonChoice2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(NumberSystem1Activity.this, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                } else if (mButtonChoice3.isChecked()) {

                    if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                        //Post Question Delay Code
                        final Handler handle = new Handler();
                        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                //Code Ends hers
                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                        };
                        handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                        mScore = mScore + 3;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        count_correct_answer++;
                        mButtonChoice3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(NumberSystem1Activity.this, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        //Post Question Delay Code
                        final Handler handle = new Handler();
                        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                //Code Ends hers
                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                        };
                        handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                        mScore = (mScore - 1);
                        count_wrong_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        mButtonChoice3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(NumberSystem1Activity.this, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                } else if (mButtonChoice4.isChecked()) {

                    if (mButtonChoice4.getText() == mAnswer) {
                        //Post Question Delay Code
                        final Handler handle = new Handler();
                        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                //Code Ends hers
                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                        };
                        handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                        mScore = mScore + 3;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        count_correct_answer++;
                        mButtonChoice4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(NumberSystem1Activity.this, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        //Post Question Delay Code
                        final Handler handle = new Handler();
                        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                //Code Ends hers
                                updateQuestion();
                            }
                        };
                        handle.postDelayed(delay, 2000);
                        mScore = (mScore - 1);
                        count_wrong_answer++;
                        updateScore(mScore);
                        mButtonChoice4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        //This line of code is optional
                        Toast.makeText(NumberSystem1Activity.this, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }

        });
    }

    public void onClear(View v) {
        /* Clears all selected radio buttons to default */
        radioGroup.clearCheck();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            times.setText("Time is up");
            Intent intent = new Intent(NumberSystem1Activity.this, ResultActivity.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("mScore", + mScore); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next

            Bundle c = new Bundle();
            c.putInt("count_correct_answer", + count_correct_answer); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(c); // Put your Correct Answer score to your next

            Bundle d = new Bundle();
            d.putInt("count_wrong_answer", + count_wrong_answer); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(d); // Put your Wrong Answer score to your next

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            .toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            times.setText(hms);
        }
    }



    private void updateQuestion(){
        if (mQuestionNumber< 30) {
            // if questions are not over then do this

            mQuestionView.setText(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
            mQuestionImageView.setImageResource(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getQuestionImages(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice1.setText(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice2.setText(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice3.setText(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice4.setText(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getChoice4(mQuestionNumber));

            mAnswer = mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
            radioGroup.clearCheck();
            mQuestionNumber++;

            //set all buttons Blue for next question
            mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue_light);
            mButtonChoice2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue_dark);
            mButtonChoice3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue_light);
            mButtonChoice4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue_dark);
        }
        else {
// if over do this
            Intent intent = new Intent(NumberSystem1Activity.this, ResultActivity.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("mScore", mScore); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next

            Bundle c = new Bundle();
            c.putInt("count_correct_answer", + count_correct_answer); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(c); // Put your Correct Answer score to your next

            Bundle d = new Bundle();
            d.putInt("count_wrong_answer", + count_wrong_answer); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(d); // Put your Wrong Answer score to your next

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    }

    private void updateScore(int point){
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);
    }



Here is my Review Activity code:


public class ReviewActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NumberSystem1QuestionBank mNumberSystem1QuestionBank = new NumberSystem1QuestionBank();

    private TextView mQuestionView;
    private ImageView mQuestionImageView;
    private TextView mExplanationView;
    private ImageView mExplanationImageView;


    private TextView mCorrectAnswer;
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_review);


        mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        mQuestionImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        mExplanationView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ExplanationText);
        mExplanationImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
        mCorrectAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CorrectAnswerText);
        final Button pre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        final Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

        updateQuestion();


        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mQuestionNumber<30){
                    mQuestionNumber++;
                    updateQuestion();
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ReviewActivity1.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });
        //if you want to disable the back button on the first question

        pre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mQuestionNumber>0) {
                    mQuestionNumber--;
                    updateQuestion();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ReviewActivity1.this, "This is the First Question. No Previous One.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // you're at the first question => no previous one
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateQuestion() {
        if (mQuestionNumber < 30) {
            // if questions are not over then do this
            mQuestionView.setText(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
            mQuestionImageView.setImageResource(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getQuestionImages(mQuestionNumber));
            mExplanationView.setText(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getExplanations(mQuestionNumber));
            mExplanationImageView.setImageResource(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getExplanationImages(mQuestionNumber));
            mCorrectAnswer.setText(mNumberSystem1QuestionBank.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber));

        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ReviewActivity1.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        //Exit The Quiz Alert Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReviewActivity1.this);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit the Review." );
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ReviewActivity1.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(ReviewActivity1.this, "Test Page Appeared.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve] to see how to ask your question better. More specifi, and higher quality questions are more likely to attract viewers and get you an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I want to save the selected button option to a string as per the questions are updated.  I used This code

Comment: ArrayList<String> answersStringArray= new ArrayList<String>();

    if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
        RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
        answersStringArray.add(ansText);
    }

Comment: but it does not seems to work